# How to assign two iface to different subnets?

Tags: networking, network-interface, subnets

I have a ethernet connection *eth0* and a wifi usb connection *wlan0* on my raspbian box which both connect to a router with internet.

In my **etc/network/interfaces** file I have a setup that allows me to connect via **SSH** to my *eth0* or *wlan0* *iface*.

```
...

iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.100
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1

...

iface wlan0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.200
        netmask 255.255.255.0

...
```

This config is fine and works as expected.

However this setup causes conflict with another software that demands each to have *iface* to be on its own subnet.

When I reconfigure my */etc/network/interfaces* file like so

```
...

iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.100
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1

...

iface wlan0 inet static
        address 192.168.2.200
        netmask 255.255.255.0

...
```

As *wlan0* is now apart of another subnet (192.168. **2** .200) I can no longer connect to it through **SSH**, I also can not reach it via *ping 192.168.2.200* from a Windows Machine.

When connected to **eth0** through **SSH**, cmd **tcpdump** returns

```
...

23:05:27.296764 IP 192.168.1.5.49846 > 192.168.1.100.ssh: Flags [.], ack 2284256, win 252, length 0
23:05:27.297540 IP 192.168.1.100.ssh > 192.168.1.5.49846: Flags [P.], seq 2284256:2284544, ack 17665, win 594, length 288
23:05:27.298780 IP 192.168.1.5.49846 > 192.168.1.100.ssh: Flags [.], ack 2284544, win 251, length 0
23:05:27.299201 IP 192.168.1.100.ssh > 192.168.1.5.49846: Flags [P.], seq 2284544:2284832, ack 17665, win 594, length 288
23:05:27.300434 IP 192.168.1.5.49846 > 192.168.1.100.ssh: Flags [.], ack 2284832, win 256, length 0
23:05:27.301316 IP 192.168.1.100.ssh > 192.168.1.5.49846: Flags [P.], seq 2284832:2285120, ack 17665, win 594, length 288
23:05:27.302296 IP 192.168.1.100.ssh > 192.168.1.5.49846: Flags [P.], seq 2285120:2285280, ack 17665, win 594, length 160
23:05:27.302712 IP 192.168.1.5.49846 > 192.168.1.100.ssh: Flags [.], ack 2285120, win 255, length 0
23:05:27.303873 IP 192.168.1.5.49846 > 192.168.1.100.ssh: Flags [.], ack 2285280, win 254, length 0

...
```

**What I have Tried**

- Updated */etc/network/interfaces* and changed netmask to **netmask 255.255.0.0**
  Still the problem remains

Comment: What's your `ip_forward` setting?

Comment: @thrid  **cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward** returns **1**, I have tried changing it to **0** but both configs do not allow a connection to 192.168. **2** .200

Comment: You probably need to verify that the traffic for wlan0 is actually not going to through eth0 since that has the default gateway information. If it goes to the `192.168.1.0/24` network, it may not know how to route the packets back to the `192.168.2.0/24` network. If it is coming in wlan0 but the response are going out eth0, you should be able to do something like `ip rule from 192.168.2.200 lookup 3` and `ip route add table 3 default via 192.168.2.1` (assuming that's the wlan0 gateway) which will tell it to use a different gateway for traffic originating from the wlan0 IP.

Comment: You can usually verify which interface it's going out either with a tcpdump or a `-j LOG` iptables rule both of which will show you the interface it's leaving out of.

Comment: @Bratchley I dont understand how the traffic possibly could be going through **wlan0** when I cannot connect to it? **wlan0** is assigned to ip 192.168.** 2 **.200, I am unable to connect in SSH to this address or receive a response when pinging it. I added to my post a cut from the cmd **tcpdump**

Comment: I'm saying that I think you may unable to connect if your TCP request comes in over wlan0 but the system's response may be going out eth0. If the network eth0 is attached to doesn't know how to route the traffic to the `192.168.2.0` network then it'll drop it which to clients will look like the system isn't responding at all.

Comment: It's called asymmetric routing and it's sometimes an issue when you have two NIC connected to two different networks.

Comment: @Bratchley Ok I think im beginning to understand, so in that case it must be setup in the router? unless we bridge in /network/interfaces?
Is there a way we can see which subnets any router is configured to accept and are open? I assume 192.168.1.x is always configured 99% of times, but I assume some routers have other subnets too at default.

Comment: For your tcpdump, we're probably more interested in recording a session where you try to connect to wlan0's IP address. For your question, updating the router would be one way of fixing the functional problem. It just may lead to performance issues if `eth0` is being used for everything but `wlan0`'s incoming packets. I would suggest trying to do something with the alternate routing table I show you earlier. Assuming the asymmetric routing is what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what is your network configuration.  In the SOHO segment the Wifi router should have taken care of this.  If you do not use any routers and that box is just connected to the ethernet and has a Wifi access point, then the only solution I can think of is to configure a bridge using **eth0** and **wlan0** and assign an IP address from 192.168.1.0/24 to that **br0** interface.

You can read on how to configure bridges on Linux at, for example, https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections

Comment: I am using a router, I was also begining to believe it is a router issue too, but is it a issue we can resolve from a config within linux?

Comment: It depends on the router.  Usually routers are configured with a bridge inside them, so they span a single network across ethernet and Wifi, so I understand why it could be difficult to assign two subnets to your box.  It would be easier to help if you shared what kind of software does not like 2 interfaces looking into the same network.

Comment: The software which rejects same subnet ifaces is **isc-dhcp-server**, which returns the error **Multiple interfaces match the same subnet: wlan0 eth0**, I can get rid of this error by changing **eth0** and **wlan0** to **....1.100** and **....2.200**

Comment: For the ISC `dhcpd` server, you could run a bridge, and then instruct `dhcpd` to listen on the bridge interface.

Comment: @thrig The problem is I am not experienced much on linux networking, let alone DHCPD, I am trying to follow tutorials online, if I attempt the bridge like you suggest its like to require me to change other settings. I would ideally like to just run **wlan0** on a 192.168. **2** .200, It would allow me to follow the tutorial this way. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Isn't your router providing DHCP already?  It would be bad two run two DHCP servers on the network?  If your router does run DHCP, just leave things as is (possibly run DHCP client on your box to get addresses) and be done with it.

Comment: @galaxy yes my router does provide DHCP, this is why I assumed we can assign an *iface* with any address and the router will forward any nessecary things it requires - this does not seem to be the case. However as for running two DHCP, I am planning to turn the Wifi Usb **wlan0** into an Access Point, but for **isc-dhcpd-server** to work it needs to be on its own subnet

Comment: If your router provides DHCP server functionality it would be very unwise to start another one - they will fight each other.  Perhaps, what you really need to do is to run DHCP *clients* on both interfaces of your box.

Comment: @galaxy Its a common project within the rasp pi community, I probably explained it partly wrong which made it sound pointless. Anyway I have since read via other forums that it could be to do with the **netmask 255.255.255.0**, and that this address only serves addresses to the default block **192.168.1.XXX**